# UIView animateWithDuration in Delphi FireMonkey

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

What is the best way to perform the same thing as UIView animateWithDuration using Delphi and FireMonkey? I would like it to work on iOS and Android (using Delphi XE5)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to animate the size of a TImageControl.

Here is what I did:

1. I dragged a TFloatAnimation control onto the canvas.
2. Using the Structure pane in Delphi, I dragged FloatAnimation1 onto ImageControl1 so it shows as a nested component of ImageControl1 in the structure pane.
3. Set the Duration, StartValue, StopValue, etc to your liking.
4. In my code I called FloatAnimation1.Start();